# Using url hash to perform click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a page that has 3 buttons to filter content on the page.

```
<section class="solution-filter">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button class="fact-sheet" data-target_category="fact-sheet" disabled="">Fact sheet</button>
        <button class="demo" data-target_category="demo">Demo</button>
        <button class="apps" data-target_category="apps">Apps and connectors</button>
    </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
</section>
```

I would like to be able to perform a click on a button depending on the url hash.

For example http://example.com/#demo
would perform a click on the `<button class="demo" data-target_category="demo">Demo</button>`

```
if ( window.location.hash ) {
    $(document).click($('<button>').data('target_category', (window.location.hash));
}
```

Comment: Looks like you already did that. Whats the problem ?

Comment: You probably just want to listen for the `hashchange` event ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea, although the syntax you're using to raise the click event is not quite right. You need to first use the `hash` value to select the element, then call `click()` or `trigger('click')` on it.

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  $('.' + window.location.hash.substr(1)).click();
}
```

Note that the `substr()` call is used to remove the `#` from the start of the string.

The above code will work for you when the page loads. If you also want to know when the hash changes after page load you can use the `hashchange` event of the `window`:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    $('.' + window.location.hash.substr(1)).click();
  }
});
```

Comment: I would suggest to add a check for whether an element matching the hash content is actually found - stuff like this tends to throw nasty errors otherwise.

Comment: @CBroe jQuery will still return an object from a selector even if nothing was found. You can be sure that there will be no errors raised from the above code if no element is found. The only way you could get an error is if the hash in the URL is not a valid selector

Comment: Yeah you’re right, I probably confused that with more complex situations (such as where you want to initialize a jQuery plugin, $('.doesnotexist').someSlider(…)`, that often results in errors when there is no matching element.) And good point about invalid selectors (could probably use a regex to check for that, but on the other hand, might not really be necessary, as long as you have no links with weird hashes floating around.)

Answer (score 2):

You need get the `button` then trigger `click()`, `$('<button>')` will create a jQuery object not target the desired element.

```
if (window.location.hash)
    $('button[data-target_category="'+window.location.hash.substr(1)+'"]').click();
```